# Error in installing available packages in kali linux

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, kali-linux, pptp

I want to set up a `PPTP VPN connection` in `kali` linux. I need to install this package: `network-manager-pptp-gnome`. I simply tried this:

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install network-manager-pptp-gnome

but I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  network-manager-pptp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2067 not upgraded.
Need to get 141 kB of archives.
After this operation, 806 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 network-manager-pptp amd64 1.2.4-5
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 network-manager-pptp-gnome amd64 1.2.4-5
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/n/network-manager-pptp/network-manager-pptp_1.2.4-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/n/network-manager-pptp/network-manager-pptp-gnome_1.2.4-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

On the other hand, this package is available in the repository:

> root@kali:~# apt-cache policy network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome

```
network-manager-pptp:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.4-5
  Version table:
     1.2.4-5 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
network-manager-pptp-gnome:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.4-5
  Version table:
     1.2.4-5 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
```

I also tried to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it didn't solve my issue. So, how can I solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggested?  (apt-get update, or try with --fix-missing)

Comment: yes, I tried. @JGroven

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the output of `apt-cache policy network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome` please?

Comment: I edited. @tripleee

Answer (score 1):

If your Apt index is very old, it will attempt to fetch files which no longer exist on the server, because they have been superseded with newer versions.  Try `apt-get update -y` before running `apt-get install`.

Comment: I tried this before, I edited my question.

Comment: [On the server](http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/n/network-manager-pptp/) I see `1.2.4-5+b1` updated Feb 19 which suggests that you are somehow still getting a stale index. (There's also an older 1.2.4-2 from January 2017.)

Comment: ... and [the Packages file](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages) (which is what `apt-get update` should fetch) lists those same versions, and no others.

Comment: I know, but I always got this error. Very annoying! @tripleee

Comment: I think this is a bug, the package is available, and I updated everything, but I cannot get the available package!

Comment: You still have *2067 not upgraded*. You should install updates *before* installing new software. Someone using Kali should now that by heart.

Answer (score -1):

I happened to get this issue on my Kali Linux in Windows subsystem.

The following worked for me and allowed me to get the updates; as per https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-repository-https-support/:

```
### Copied from kali Support - 
root@kali:~# apt install apt-transport-https

root@kali:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

# deb-src https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
root@kali:~#
```

I used `vi` to edit the source file and add the https mirror in it.

Now any update or upgrade operation preformed against our mirrors will be HTTPS enabled:

```
root@kali:~# apt update
Hit:1 https://archive-3.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@kali:~#
```